# Protractor: Open new webdriver after every describe?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I need to open a new web driver after every describe (e2e test i run)

The reason is that i need to clear my browser cache (not cookies),

Every time i try to use `ptor.quit()` / `browser.driver.quit()`, i get this exception:

> "Error: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you
>   call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used."

Comment: If you are testing on chrome, you could try to run it in incognito mode. `capabilities: { 'browserName': 'chrome', 'chromeOptions': { 'args': ['incognito'] } }`

Comment: Careful if you need to take screenshots, etc. Incognito may block some functionality on account of the privacy features.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't start new webDriver session after each `describe`, but in turn use `afterAll()` functionality that Jasmine provides which runs after all specs in describe are finished running. In other words `afterAll()` runs after each describe and will suffice your need. Do not quit after all your specs are completed in a describe as it stops the webdriver execution itself. Here's how to do it -

```
afterAll(function() {
    browser.executeScript('window.sessionStorage.clear();'); //clear session
    browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();'); //clear local storage
});
```

Comment: shall i quit(); or close beowser after the end of my tests ot avoid jasmine time out error ?

Comment: @Emna If you are getting Jasmine timeout error then you need to look into it and fix it instead of closing the browser, which is not a good practice.

Comment: I still have the same issue, i tried to fix it with many ways , like increasing defaulttimeout in jasmineNodeOpts, i tried also to make brwser.sleep(5000); to wait until the site is loaded ! i tried also allScriptsTimeout: 15000. 
But always i have the same problem : at the moment of login it's fine login button is clicked and user is redirected to home page after that i want to click into a button but the second test is also failed

Comment: @Emna please update your question with the code ur facing issue with or ask a new question, so that people can help.

Comment: here my question i 'm updating it , i will update code now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37008132/what-are-the-methods-we-can-use-to-wait-for-an-angular-site-to-be-loaded-in-orde

Answer (score 2):

May be you want to empty browser's local storage?

```
afterEach(function() {
    browser.executeScript('window.sessionStorage.clear();');
    browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();');
});`
```