# What are the methods we can use to wait for an angular site to be loaded in order to test it with protractor?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, timeout, protractor, end-to-end

What are the methods we can use to wait for an Angular site to be loaded in order to test it with protractor in order to avoid this error caused by jasmine : `A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow` ?
I'm able to make the login and go to home page that test is passed, but from the second test i have problems of jasmine.
[image: Here the config file and test spec]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have configured this problem by adding this function into my config file :

```
    onPrepare: function() {
      return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) {
        var browserName = config.capabilities.browserName;
        browser.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60000);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the browser object of Protractor to wait for angular.

As soon as you load your page add the following :

```
browser.waitForAngular();
```

Comment: when i delete all browser.sleep(timeout_in_millis); from my test and i put browser.waitForAngular(); the test is passed but the problem home page isn't shown ! it closes at the moment when login button is tapped!

Comment: Are you waiting for the page to be fully loaded or waiting for some action?

Comment: Yes for the page to load, and when that step is fine i'll do my test on home page

Comment: If you are using promise on the click, then you don't need to add any wait or sleep... can you add some actions/assertions on the home page after the click? You can add the angular wait right after you do the get... also browser.driver.wait() can also be used to check if the specific element is loaded on the page. You can use that to check for any element on the home page is loaded or not.

Comment: I made some tests inside the home page click into a button for example i had the same error ! even with browser.waitForAngular();

Comment: protractor automatically applies the `browser.waitForAngular()` call before every webDriver action

Answer (score 1):

This error means that *your test took too much time* and exceeded the [default Jasmine spec timeout interval](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#timeouts-from-jasmine) which is 30 seconds by default (It looks like you've configured the timeout to be 60 seconds). It can be configured in the `jasmineNodeOpts` object in your Protractor config:

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {defaultTimeoutInterval: timeout_in_millis},
```

The solution is usually use-case specific and it usually indicates there is an error in the test code. In order to fully understand what is going, we would need to see the code itself.

In your particular case, for starters, you should try moving the "ignore synchronization" and the `browser.get()` part into the `beforeEach`. Also, since you are turning the sync off, you need to [wait](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) for the element to be present on the page before interacting with it:

```
describe("my app", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get("...");
    });

    it("should make the login test", function () { 
        // ...
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        var username = element(by.model("credentials.username"));
        browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(username), 10000);

        username.sendKeys("RET02");
        // ...
    });
});
```

And, I am not sure if you really need to turn the synchronization off since this is an AngularJS page you are working with.

Comment: Actually it is configured to :jasmineNodeOpts: { 3000000 } 
Shall i put it bigger than that ?

Comment: @Emna oh, interesting, the console dump you've posted indicates that the test took 60 seconds only. Anyway, could you post the test itself? - may help to understand what is going on.. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I put the config and testspec also

Comment: ok thanks, but te site is Angular JS is it logic to put  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; ?

Comment: @Emna yeah, you might not need to turn the sync off. Does it work without the `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` line?

Comment: with `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` within before each function , the element cannot be found : (username)and when i delete this line totally the test is done until the home page is opened but it fails with the jasmine error i have already mentionned !

Comment: @Emna okay, updated the answer. If the sync is off, the explicit wait(s) would be required.

Comment: It's ok now i can get into the login page and the test is passed, but when trying to click into a button in home page i got the same error of jasmine timeout !

Answer (score 1):

Can you wait for a url? 
Let's assume that when you click on the login button your page is redirected to another url. So you can wait for the expected url. Example:

```
browser.driver.wait(function() {
        return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
            // Dashboard is the loaded url after login (in this example)
            return /Dashboard/.test(url);
        });
    }, 60000);
```

This code waits for the page `browser.baseUrl/Dashboard` to be loaded, for 60 seconds

Comment: I have tried your idea the site is succesfully loaded but the problem of jasmine error persists !

Comment: When you comment the first `expect(getTittle())...` the error persists? Are all the commands executed (those sendKeys and click)? Can you attach the html source in the post? PS: Does your baseUrl really have this path <ip>/jws/ftablet or it must be just the ip address?

Comment: IT's ok now, for login but when i want to click into a button in home page i came back to that error of jasmine !